How can I check if a session is in a specific date? [TradingView Indicator]
I'm writing a pine script for TradingView (Indicator), and I have a specific session.
I want that the session will be drawn on the chart only on the previous day.
for example today is 03/05/24, I want that my code will be only drawn on 02/05/24.
This is my code:
my_session = input.session("0400-0430", '', group="Tests")
is_my_session = math.sign(nz(time("5", my_session)))

get_range(session, session_name, session_css)=>
    var t = 0 
    var max = high
    var min = low
    var box bx = na
    var label lbl = na 
    
    if session > session[1]
        t := time
        max := high
        min := low

        bx := box.new(n, max, n, min
          , bgcolor = color.new(session_css, bg_transp)
          , border_color = show_outline ? session_css : na
          , border_style = line.style_dotted)

        if show_txt
            lbl := label.new(t, max, session_name
              , xloc = xloc.bar_time
              , textcolor = session_css
              , style = label.style_label_down
              , color = color.new(color.white, 100)
              , size = size.tiny)

    if session and session == session[1]
        max := math.max(high, max)
        min := math.min(low, min)

        box.set_top(bx, max)
        box.set_rightbottom(bx, n, min)

        if show_txt
            label.set_xy(lbl, int(math.avg(t, time)), max)

get_range(is_my_session, "My session", color.new(24,24,24))

I was trying comparing the time and timenow but it didn't work.

You can use the built-in variables year, month, day to figure out if it is a given day. And then use that as a condition to draw your boxes.
date_cond = (year == 2024) and (month == 5) and (dayofmonth == 2)


Just to be on the super-nitpicking side, this kind of date checking will miss the start of the day twice a year, when moving to and away from daylight saving.
